# Cauchy Criterion for $L^r$ convergence.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

If trying to prove the next result (stated without proof in one of my Professor's course notes):

> For any $r \ge 1$, we get: $X_n \stackrel{r}{\to} X \text{ (with $X \in L^r$)} \; \Leftrightarrow \; \mathbb{E}[|X_n|^r] < \infty, \, \forall n \; \text{ and }  \;\mathbb{E}[|X_n - X_m|^r] \to 0 \text{ as } n,m \to \infty. $

Note: $X_n \stackrel{r}{\to} X $ means $E[|X_n - X|^r|] \to 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty$.

My attempt:

(1) $\Rightarrow:$ By Minkowski's inequality, we have:
\begin{align*}
    &  \hspace{-3cm}\mathbb{E}[|X_n - X_m|^r]^{1/r} = \mathbb{E}[|X_n - X+X-X_m|^r]^{1/r} \\
    & \hspace{.05cm} \le \mathbb{E}[|X_n-X|^r]^{1/r} + \mathbb{E}[|X_m-X|^r]^{1/r} \to 0 \text{ as } n,m \to \infty
\end{align*}

(2) $\Leftarrow$: Notice that, $\forall \epsilon > 0$:
\begin{align*}
    & \mathbb{P}(|X_m-X_n| > \epsilon) \le \frac{\mathbb{E}[|X_n-X_m|^r]}{\epsilon^r} \to 0 \text{ as }n,m \to \infty.
\end{align*}
In conclusion, $X_n \to X$ in $\mathbb{P}$ therefore there exists subsequence $n_k$ where, $X_{n_k} \to X$ a.s. as $k \to \infty$. This tells us that:
\begin{align*}
    & \mathbb{E}[|X_n - X|^r] = \mathbb{E}[\lim_{k \to \infty}|X_n - X_{n_k}|^r] \le \liminf_k \mathbb{E}[|X_n - X_{n_k}|^r].
\end{align*}
by Fatou's Lemma. Take $n \to \infty$, apply Cauchy criterion. The result holds. Lastly, to show that $X \in L^r$,
\begin{align*}
    & \mathbb{E}[|X|^r] = \mathbb{E}[\lim_{k \to \infty}|X_{n_k}|^r] \le \liminf_{k \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[|X_{n_k}|^r]
\end{align*}
This is where I'm lost/stuck. I want to say that:

\begin{align}
& ... \le \liminf_{k \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[|X_{n_k}|^r] \le \sup_k \mathbb{E}[|X_{n_k}|^r] < \infty
\end{align}
since $\mathbb{E}[|X_n|^r] < \infty$ for all $n$. However, I don't think this is true (take a sequence $a_n = n, \, \forall n$). Any comments or ideas on how to prove that the limiting random variable $X$ here is integrable would be really thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(2) $\Leftarrow$:

By the assumption, for every $\epsilon$ there exists $M_\epsilon$ such that $$\forall n,m \ge M_\epsilon, \quad  \mathbb{E}[|X_n-X_m|^r] \le \epsilon \,.$$
Take $n>M_1$.
You already proved that
\begin{align*}
        & \mathbb{E}[|X_n - X|^r] = \mathbb{E}[\lim_{k \to \infty}|X_n - X_{n_k}|^r] \le \liminf_k \mathbb{E}[|X_n - X_{n_k}|^r] \le 1.
    \end{align*}

One more application of Minkowski's inequality gives
$$\mathbb{E}[|X|^r]^{1/r}=\|X\|_r \le \|X_n\|_r +\|X-X_n\|_r \le \|X_n\|_r+1 \,.$$

Comment: Thank you. Greatly appreciative :)